# Check Which Order Buttons Are Pressed Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app that I need to check which order buttons are pressed in. I had 3 buttons and if they are pressed in the incorrect order I will have a UIAlertView. How can I check the order of presses?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wire up an action to the buttons (like "Touch Up Inside"), and have it log which buttons are pressed, and maybe have a counter incrementing as well.  Then when the counter gets to three, have it go through the list of button presses, and verify if they are the order you anticipate.

Below is an example of what I mean.  For this example, you have to wire up all 3 buttons "Touch Up Inside" to that same IBAction.  Of course you replace the NSLogs with your UIAlertView, but this shows the gist of what I said.

```
@interface comboSOTestViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *buttonTitles;

@end

@implementation comboSOTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.buttonTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

- (IBAction)comboButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.buttonTitles addObject:sender.titleLabel.text];

    if (self.buttonTitles.count > 2)
    {
        BOOL bad = NO;
        NSArray *correctOrder = @[@"Second", @"Third", @"First"];
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (![self.buttonTitles[i] isEqualToString:correctOrder[i]])
            {
                bad = YES;
            }
        }

        if (bad == YES)
        {
            NSLog(@"WRONG ORDER");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"CORRECT ORDER");
        }
    }
}
```